# Ajax form with separate action values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact form with multiple submit buttons which have different action values.

```
<form action="confirm.php" data-query="send.php" method="POST"  class="form">
```

I am using data-query attribute to fetch action link for one of the submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit B">
```

Ajax code is below:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#submit2').click(function(e) {
            var thisForm = $('.form');
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.form').fadeOut(function() {
                $("#loading").fadeIn(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: thisForm.attr("data-query"),
                        data: thisForm.serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#loading").fadeOut(function() {
                                $("#success").fadeIn();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

I am getting the success message but the php code isn't getting executed.
The PHP code is working fine without the AJAX method.

Comment: Run separate AJAX with each button.

Comment: I want AJAX for only the second button.

Comment: Why have `data-query`? Just put the `url:'send.php'` into AJAX. The PHP at `send.php` has to `echo` or `print` something which gets passed to your `data` argument on `success`. A regular form submission with the other button will reload or go to a page the HTML `<form action` attribute suggests, possibly changing scroll position and creating a flash effect.

Comment: I tried that too. I used data-query to make it simpler for the other developer I am working with. 
In the PHP file, this is getting redirected to, there is an IF condition before the main code which checks whether the right submit button was pressed. 
Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`.serialize()` doesn't give you button values, you'll have to add it manually, something like

```
data: thisForm.serialize()+'?button2=Submit%20B',
```

Comment: Still no luck.
How can I find the error log for AJAX calls?